# How to combine these two regex passes into one?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I have a few thousand strings that have one of these two forms:

`SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1k3.this - $3.57 KnownWord`

`SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1k3.that - 4.5% KnownWord`

The `SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1ke.this` part may contain uppercase and lowercase characters, digits, periods, dashes, and spaces.  It is always followed by a space-dash-space pattern.

I want to pull out the Title (the part before the space-dash-space separator) and the Amount, which is right before `KnownWord`.

So for these two strings I'd like:

`SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1k3.this, $3.57` and

`SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1k3.that, 4.5%`.

This code works (using Perl equivalent Regular Expressions)

```
$my_string = "SomeT1tle-ThatL00ks L1k3.this - $3.57 KnownWord";

$pattern_title = "/^(.*?)\x20\x2d\x20/";
$pattern_amount = "/([0-9.$%]+) KnownWord$/";

preg_match_all($pattern_title, $my_string, $matches_title);
preg_match_all($pattern_amount, $my_string, $matches_amount);

echo $matches_title[1][0] . "  " . $matches_amount[1][0] . "<br>";
```

I tried putting both patterns together:

```
$pattern_together_doesnt_work = "/^(.*?)\x20\x2d\x20([0-9.$%]+) KnownWord$/";
```

but the first part of the pattern always matches the whole thing, even with the "lazy" part (`.*?` rather than `.*`).  I can't negative-match spaces and dashes, because the title itself can contain either.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
/^(.*?)\x20\x2d\x20([0-9.$%]+) KnownWord$/
```

Comment: OK, that worked.  (Don't know why it didn't before.)  I had an extra forward slash in the expression that I edited out.  I also used `$matches[1][0]` and `$matches[2][0]` to get the right fields out.  Thanks for talking me through it!